# How to sort a column in pivot table in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe name `pivot_df`

```
PRODUCT YIELD   UNIT_TESTED WEIGHTAGE
   D    82.1042     401      0.1565
   E    96.0687     1512    0.5901
   T    73.2952      495    0.1932
   A    84.9918      739    0.2884
   V    71.822      7108    2.7740
   G    88.889      1532    0.5979
```

I want to sort the value in the `WEIGHTAGE` column in descending(highest to low) and print the top 5.

The desired output:

```
PRODUCT YIELD   UNIT_TESTED WEIGHTAGE
   V    71.822      7108    2.7740
   G    88.889      1532    0.5979
   E    96.0687     1512    0.5901
   A    84.9918      739    0.2884
   T    73.2952      495    0.1932
   D    82.1042      401    0.1565
```

I have tried `print(pivot_df.iloc[pivot_df.sum(axis=1).argsort()])`. It kinda sort, but not like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by using `.sort_values()` on the dataframe and specific the column. Use the `ascending=` parameter to specifiy the order direction. To get the top 5 you can use either `.head(5)` or `.iloc[:5]`

```
print(df.sort_values(['WEIGHTAGE'], ascending=False).head(5))


#   PRODUCT    YIELD  UNIT_TESTED  WEIGHTAGE
# 4       V  71.8220         7108     2.7740
# 5       G  88.8890         1532     0.5979
# 1       E  96.0687         1512     0.5901
# 3       A  84.9918          739     0.2884
# 2       T  73.2952          495     0.1932
```